# Why does file_put_contents not append data to a file?

Tags: php, php4

I have a complex php4 code and want to write something to a file, using `file_put_contents`, like the following:

```
$iCounter = 0;
foreach blah...
    ... code
    file_put_contents("/tmp/debug28364363264936214", "test" . $iCounter++ . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    ...code
```

I am using `FILE_APPEND` to append the data to the given file, I am sure that what I print does not contain control characters, the random number sequence makes sure the file is not used in any other context, and the counter variable  (only used for the printout) is used to control how often `file_put_contents` is called.

Executing the code and looking at the file content I just see

```
test8
```

while I expect to see

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
```

Is there a problem with my syntax? Maybe the code does not work for php4? What else can I use instead?

P.S. I am working on a very large, quite ancient php4 project, so there is no way to recode the project in php5. Not within 2 years...

Comment: Because file_put_contents() ___overwrites___ the existing file, as per the documentation

Comment: It should work .... perfectly what version and os are you using  ? Please note that `file_put_contents` is PHP5 not PHP4 ???

Comment: Its 4.4.9-pl0-gentoo on 2.6.30-gentoo-r4. But if this function only exists in PHP5, why do I get something? It should not work at all I would assume.

Comment: @MarkBaker there is a caveat, you can use `FILE_APPEND` as a flag on 3rd param. I also didn't know this till today, which is why i love SO :)

Comment: @Alex the PHP doc says (PHP 5) not sure why you have it in 4 but the date `FILE_APPEND` was introduced was not specified either ..

Comment: the code might be in php4 but it should work in php5 if using php5 which you should be. you just need to recode the errors.

Comment: @Alex i am sure i answer the question 1 hr before chosen answer with the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `fopen();` `file_put_contents()` is php5.

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/debug28364363264936214", "a+");
fwrite($file, "test" . $iCounter++ . "\n");
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use foreach it there is an array input it will be a similuar procedure

```
for ($iCounter = 1; $iCounter <= 10; $iCounter++) {

$test_var .= "test" . $iCounter . PHP_EOL;

}


if (file_exists("/tmp/debug28364363264936214")) {

file_put_contents("/tmp/debug28364363264936214", $test_var, FILE_APPEND);

    echo "The file was written";
} else {
    echo "The file was not written";
}
```

php4 code

```
if (file_exists("/tmp/debug28364363264936214")) {

$fp = fopen('/tmp/debug28364363264936214', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $test_var);
fclose($fp);

    echo "The file was written";
} else {
    echo "The file was not written";
}
```

your code might be in php4 but it should work in php5 if using php5 which you should be. you just need to recode the errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append data then do as follows

```
 $file = "yourfile.txt";
 $data = file_get_contents($file);
 $data =  $data . $newdata;
 file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: But whyn is my code not working? Or why does it somewhat work for php4?